# Anyone know a good (paid) US Proxy for testing web sites?

Tags: proxy

I need to test my web site from a US perspective (most of my customers are from the US, and I'm in Australia). I'd like to be able to run through an e-commerce transaction which relies third-party gateways, SSL, etc., and have it appear as though I'm in America. The free web-based proxies don't really cut it. I don't mind paying money. Maybe something VPN-based. Any recommendations?

Comment: is this question more suitable for serverfault.com or superuser.com sites?

Comment: I'm particularly interested in recommendations from programmers - I'm certain to get answers from other sites, but I'm not sure it will be what I want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, I ended up subscribing to surfbouncer.com (a VPN-based service with servers in 8 countries) and so far it's working well.